# Unable to generate android apk from Sencha touch project using sencha cmd 3.1.2.342

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-cmd

I have downloaded sencha command v3.1.2.342 , sencha touch2.4.0-commercial and have installed ruby 1.9.3p545 and installed sass and compass and ant and installed jdk 1.7 and set classpath ,path successfully in my windows 7 64 bit machine.

PS : The problem i am facing is to Unable to generate android skeleton project from sencha touch example project.

I have executed the following command **sencha app package build packager.json**

All my android directortes i.e., android skeleton project were created and then deleted automatically without generating apk.

For this problem , I searched in their site forum , http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?199120-ST2-Native-Packaging-command-fails-on-Windows-7-x64 , **they have mentioned that change the outputPath because output path cannot be inside the app path itself. Setting outputPath somewhere else, e.g. on the Desktop, completely solved the issue.**

I have tried nothing works for me.
Error I am getting :

> Could not copy web application ./\ to output folder D:/build/\assets\
>       Failed to package application
>
> ```
> [ERR] stbuild exited with non-zero code : 3
> ```

Full stack trace:

```
D:\San\olderversion\webv2>sencha app package build packager.json
Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342
[ERR]
Created directory D:\build\src\com\san\App
Added file D:\build\src\com\san\App\STActivity.java
Created directory D:\build\res
Created directory D:\build\bin
Created directory D:\build\libs
Created directory D:\build\res\values
Added file D:\build\res\values\strings.xml
Created directory D:\build\res\layout
Added file D:\build\res\layout\main.xml
Created directory D:\build\res\drawable-xhdpi
Created directory D:\build\res\drawable-hdpi
Created directory D:\build\res\drawable-mdpi
Created directory D:\build\res\drawable-ldpi
Added file D:\build\AndroidManifest.xml
Added file D:\build\build.xml
Added file D:\build\proguard-project.txt
A subdirectory or file D:\build\\\libs\ already exists.
A subdirectory or file D:\build\\\assets\ already exists.
""C:/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86/sdk\tools\android" create project --target android-17 --name App --activity STActivity --path "D:/build/\/" --package com.san
.App"
Could not copy web application ./\ to output folder D:/build/\\assets\
Failed to package application

[ERR] stbuild exited with non-zero code : 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those instructions are rather old (27 Apr 2012).  Sencha now encourages devs to use PhoneGap build in place of their older Sencha native build.  Tons more plugins in PhoneGap and ST 2.4.0 include many wrappers for PhoneGap APIs.

You might also want to have a look at my app for this

- https://github.com/tohagan/stlive
- README includes step by step instructions and a detailed install guide.
- ST Live performs `app build native` to perform the PhoneGap build.

Comment: Thanks for the github link

Comment: Please provide your suggestion on this.http://stackoverflow.com/q/30931036/424413