# Unable to run the Sencha Cordova project in Windows 8.1 Computer

Tags: windows, cordova, sencha-touch-2, windows-8.1, sencha-cmd5

I have downloaded the sample Sencha project from Lee in her blog [(Lee's Sample Project)](http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/getting-started-with-sencha-touch-2-build-a-weather-utility-app-part-1/#.VYJjEul1OE9).

I have installed all the necessary software like Sencha Cmd version 5.0.1.231 , Ruby, Compass, sass, Java, Node.js,Sencha Touch, Cordova in my windows 8.1 machine before proceeding to work.

I have followed the steps from this answer ([Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18850246/424413))

When I run the following Sencha Command inside the Sencha Project which I downloaded.

```
sencha app build package
```

It says the project builds on older version of Sencha, Please Upgrade to new Sencha Cmd Version.

so I have run the following Command.

```
sencha app upgrade
```

After that ,I repeated the step 1, i.e, I run the same command

```
sencha app build package
```

I have created a new folder namely LeeCode inside my tomcat webapps directory.

Now I have copied all the files inside my sencha project and pasted it inside LeeCode folder.

After doing the above step ,I have opened Chorme Browser and type http://localhost:8080/LeeCode

I was able to see that the project is working fine in Chrome browser.

Now I have created new Cordova project by issuing the following command in command prompt.

```
cordova create LeeCodeCordova
```

Then I have added the platform by using the following command,

```
cordova platform add windows
```

Then I have removed all content of www folder in my cordova project.

Now I have copied the Sencha files from LeeCode folder (which is inside my Tomcat webapps directory).

Then I have run the following command

```
Cordova build windows
```

Then I have run the following command

```
Cordova run windows -- --win
```

I was able only to see the first screen after that it hangs , I was not able to see the next screen in Cordova, but if run the same project as mentioned in chrome , I was able to all the screens in the project.

Comment: Are you able to do any remote debugging to see the JavaScript console for the WebView?

Comment: I was not able to do Remote Debugging , since the problem is that the first screen of the app is not shown , instead it stuck while showing the loader screen itself.

Comment: @arthurakay does -webkit-linear-gradient works on windows8.1

Comment: Probably inside Cordova's webview (which is webkit), but I doubt any "-webkit" CSS prefixes work in IE